# Modifing bibliography and citation display

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, citing

I put all my references in a file `PaperBib.bib`, and call `\bibliography{PaperBib}` in the end. I have several questions:

1. For the references part, is it possible to make my own style? For instance, I want to print only `Author`, `Title`, `booktitle`, `pages`, `volume` and `year`; and ignore `note`.
2. For where I use `\cite{...}` in the paper, at the moment only a number closed by `[]` is shown to represent the reference. How could I print `[authors year]`  or `[authors number`] when I want?

**Edit1:** By the way, I am using `bibtex`.

Comment: Are you using `bibtex` or `biblatex`?

Comment: I am using `bibtex`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use the `natbib` package, which provides a few additional citation commands, along with several bibliography citation styles, one of which may meet your needs. Your query is not very specific, but it appears that you're after some author-year citation style rather than one of the numeric citation styles. `Natbib` offers several author-year citation systems. You can find the documentation for the `natbib` package on any CTAN (Central TeX Archive Network) repository.

Answer (score 1):

I’d prefere `biblatex` instead of `natbib` because it’s more flexible and highly customizable.